# Unable to change ActionBar background in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

First Info : MinAPI 16, Problem :

I'm able to modify the background color, but not the SystemBar color just like Lollipop ( I'm on Lollipop ), The SystemBar color is according to my device theme, Not according to my App theme.

I'm supporting Multiply theme changing, Light/Dark, in my app, And the ListActivity got a bit problems in using AppCompat (No toolbar/ textColor is wrong ), So I've set the activity theme to the following theme :

```
    <style name="AppThemeOld" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

MyActionBar :

```
   <style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="background">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
</style>
```

I've added a bit codes to check if it's applying the MyActionBar custom theme, and the answer it's not applying it as an actionbar .

What's the solution ?

```
public class AppsActivity extends AppCompatListActivity {
private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private AppsAdapter listadaptor = null;
public static List<PackagesItem> Packages;
private boolean IsLightThemeEnabled;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    IsLightThemeEnabled = Prefs.getBoolean("Theme",false);
    if(IsLightThemeEnabled)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light);

    }
    else {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }

    if(getActionBar() !=null)
    {
       // getActionBar().set
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.appslist);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
    try {

        String AppPackage = app.packageName;
        String AppName = app.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();

        Packages = SharedPreferencesTools.getOrderedItems(this);

        boolean IsItAdded = false;
        for(PackagesItem list : Packages)
        {
            if(list.getPackage().equals(AppPackage))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,AppName + " "+ getResources().getString(R.string.already_added_warning),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                IsItAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!IsItAdded) {
            Toast.makeText(this,AppName + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.added_success),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Packages.add(new PackagesItem(AppPackage,""));
        }
        SharedPreferencesTools.setOrderedItems(this, Packages);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(AppsActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(AppsActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finish();
}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return applist;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

        listadaptor = new AppsAdapter(AppsActivity.this,
                R.layout.appitem, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(listadaptor);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(AppsActivity.this, null,
                "Loading application info...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The default color is according to my system theme color* .

Answer (score 2):

The `ListActivity` does not inherit from `AppCompatActivity` so you'll need to modify it if you want similar behavior. In one of my applications I created my own `ListActivity` here is the code:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public abstract class AppCompatListActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {

    static final int INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID = 0x00ff0001;
    static final int INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID = 0x00ff0002;
    static final int INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID = 0x00ff0003;

    final private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    final private Runnable mRequestFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mList.focusableViewAvailable(mList);
        }
    };

    final private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            onListItemClick((ListView)parent, v, position, id);
        }
    };

    ListAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mList;
    View mEmptyView;
    TextView mStandardEmptyView;
    View mProgressContainer;
    View mListContainer;
    CharSequence mEmptyText;
    boolean mListShown;

    public AppCompatListActivity() {
    }

    /**
     * Provide default implementation to return a simple list view.  Subclasses
     * can override to replace with their own layout.  If doing so, the
     * returned view hierarchy <em>must</em> have a ListView whose id
     * is {@link android.R.id#list android.R.id.list} and can optionally
     * have a sibling view id {@link android.R.id#empty android.R.id.empty}
     * that is to be shown when the list is empty.
     *
     * <p>If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
     * consider including the standard layout {@link android.R.layout#list_content}
     * in your layout file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard
     * behavior of ListFragment.  In particular, this is currently the only
     * way to have the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.
     */
    /*
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FrameLayout root = new FrameLayout(context);

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        LinearLayout pframe = new LinearLayout(context);
        pframe.setId(INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID);
        pframe.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        pframe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pframe.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(context, null,
                android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        pframe.addView(progress, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        root.addView(pframe, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        FrameLayout lframe = new FrameLayout(context);
        lframe.setId(INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID);

        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setId(INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        lframe.addView(tv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        ListView lv = new ListView(getActivity());
        lv.setId(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setDrawSelectorOnTop(false);
        lframe.addView(lv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        root.addView(lframe, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        root.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ensureList();
    }
    */

    /**
     * Detach from list view.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRequestFocus);
        mList = null;
        mListShown = false;
        mEmptyView = mProgressContainer = mListContainer = null;
        mStandardEmptyView = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
     * Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call
     * getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the
     * data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param l The ListView where the click happened
     * @param v The view that was clicked within the ListView
     * @param position The position of the view in the list
     * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked
     */
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }

    /**
     * Provide the cursor for the list view.
     */
    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        boolean hadAdapter = mAdapter != null;
        mAdapter = adapter;
        if (mList != null) {
            mList.setAdapter(adapter);
            if (!mListShown && !hadAdapter) {
                // The list was hidden, and previously didn't have an
                // adapter.  It is now time to show it.
                //setListShown(true, getView().getWindowToken() != null);
                setListShown(true, false);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the currently selected list item to the specified
     * position with the adapter's data
     *
     * @param position -
     */
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        ensureList();
        mList.setSelection(position);
    }

    /**
     * Get the position of the currently selected list item.
     */
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        ensureList();
        return mList.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    /**
     * Get the cursor row ID of the currently selected list item.
     */
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        ensureList();
        return mList.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    /**
     * Get the activity's list view widget.
     */
    public ListView getListView() {
        ensureList();
        return mList;
    }

    /**
     * The default content for a ListFragment has a TextView that can
     * be shown when the list is empty.  If you would like to have it
     * shown, call this method to supply the text it should use.
     */
    public void setEmptyText(CharSequence text) {
        ensureList();
        if (mStandardEmptyView == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't be used with a custom content view");
        }
        mStandardEmptyView.setText(text);
        if (mEmptyText == null) {
            mList.setEmptyView(mStandardEmptyView);
        }
        mEmptyText = text;
    }

    /**
     * Control whether the list is being displayed.  You can make it not
     * displayed if you are waiting for the initial data to show in it.  During
     * this time an indeterminant progress indicator will be shown instead.
     *
     * <p>Applications do not normally need to use this themselves.  The default
     * behavior of ListFragment is to start with the list not being shown, only
     * showing it once an adapter is given with {@link #setListAdapter(ListAdapter)}.
     * If the list at that point had not been shown, when it does get shown
     * it will be do without the user ever seeing the hidden state.
     *
     * @param shown If true, the list view is shown; if false, the progress
     * indicator.  The initial value is true.
     */
    public void setListShown(boolean shown) {
        setListShown(shown, true);
    }

    /**
     * Like {@link #setListShown(boolean)}, but no animation is used when
     * transitioning from the previous state.
     */
    public void setListShownNoAnimation(boolean shown) {
        setListShown(shown, false);
    }

    /**
     * Control whether the list is being displayed.  You can make it not
     * displayed if you are waiting for the initial data to show in it.  During
     * this time an indeterminant progress indicator will be shown instead.
     *
     * @param shown If true, the list view is shown; if false, the progress
     * indicator.  The initial value is true.
     * @param animate If true, an animation will be used to transition to the
     * new state.
     */
    private void setListShown(boolean shown, boolean animate) {
        ensureList();
        if (mProgressContainer == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't be used with a custom content view");
        }
        if (mListShown == shown) {
            return;
        }
        mListShown = shown;
        if (shown) {
            if (animate) {
                mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
                mListContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
            } else {
                mProgressContainer.clearAnimation();
                mListContainer.clearAnimation();
            }
            mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mListContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            if (animate) {
                mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
                mListContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
            } else {
                mProgressContainer.clearAnimation();
                mListContainer.clearAnimation();
            }
            mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mListContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the ListAdapter associated with this activity's ListView.
     */
    public ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    private void ensureList() {
        if (mList != null) {
            return;
        }

        View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Content view not yet created");
        }
        if (root instanceof ListView) {
            mList = (ListView)root;
        } else {
            mStandardEmptyView = (TextView)root.findViewById(INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID);
            if (mStandardEmptyView == null) {
                mEmptyView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            } else {
                mStandardEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mProgressContainer = root.findViewById(INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID);
            mListContainer = root.findViewById(INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID);
            View rawListView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            if (!(rawListView instanceof ListView)) {
                if (rawListView == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is " +
                                    "'android.R.id.list'");
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' "
                                + "that is not a ListView class");
            }
            mList = (ListView)rawListView;
            if (mEmptyView != null) {
                mList.setEmptyView(mEmptyView);
            } else if (mEmptyText != null) {
                mStandardEmptyView.setText(mEmptyText);
                mList.setEmptyView(mStandardEmptyView);
            }
        }
        mListShown = true;
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            ListAdapter adapter = mAdapter;
            mAdapter = null;
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            // We are starting without an adapter, so assume we won't
            // have our data right away and start with the progress indicator.
            if (mProgressContainer != null) {
                setListShown(false, false);
            }
        }
        mHandler.post(mRequestFocus);
    }
}
```

Most of the code was borrowed from the `ListFragment` implementation which is why you'll see commented out `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` methods.

Comment: So there's no solution without cloning your code ? It's a bit difficult to make it work again (it's a ListActivity which bring Installed Apps), for example, editing that according to system color ActionBar ?

Comment: Copying my code that extends 'AppCompatActivity' would be the simplest as that's what the action bar expects. Just change your extends on the existing class you created to the new one I posted.

Comment: It worked, But my previous list generated a list of Installed Apps, after switching it's not displaying, can you please check the OP (Edited). *It shows the progress dialog, but doesn't show the list at all.

Comment: @AboHani - Does it show your `@android:id/empty` `TextView` (assuming you have one in the layout)? You're using `@android:id/list` for the id of your `ListView` correct?

Comment: I don't have one actually, I've posted the coded in the #1 check it out please. + and yes " android:id="@android:id/list" " it's like you said .

Comment: I would start debugging with log statements or the debugger to verify you are getting to the correct spots. For instance: Does `applist` have items in the `doInBackground`? Do you make it to the `onPostExecute`? The other problem could be in your `appslist` layout since the `AppCompatActivity` uses it's own inflater. So maybe something changed there (ie: I hate the `CoordinatorLayout` as it often causes issues but wouldn't have "worked" in the old `ListActivity`)

Comment: My 'appslist' is a listview inside linearlayout, I'm using a a simple layout it was working before extending this class, the log doesn't show anything only " activity_request / activity_idle " logs, If you want i can post the layout files (nothing strange in them, an item layout and list layout ) .

Comment: I've just added a useless logs to check if the methods are being executed, And YES they're being executed, And the loop throw installedApps also being executed, I got a looped log message for every installed app, So what's the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103344/discussion-between-cory-charlton-and-abo-hani).